# Simplify python code- iterative compare in if

Tags: python, regex

I want to simplify this statement in python.

```
if string=='M' or string=='m' or string=='Male':
      print "OK"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if string in ["M", "m", "Male"]:
    print "OK"
```